# CSS subnav text hover color not working

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I am having trouble getting the subnav menu text to change color when you hover over it. What I am trying to build is a navigation menu that has a subnav. The hover state for the subnav links changes the background color and text color. I haven't been able to get this to work, currently only the background changes on rollover, and not the text.

Here is a link to an example of the navigation:
http://confinedfoodie.com/test/contact.html
The subnav can be found under "video post" in "WHAT WE DO".

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav id="primary-nav"><!-- Navigation -->
          <ul>

    <li><a href="#nowhere">WHAT WE DO</a><!-- what we do -->
                <ul><!-- hidden links level 1 -->
                    <li><a href="radio-production.html">Radio Production</a></li>
                    <li><a href="voice-casting.html">Voice Casting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nowhere">Video Post</a><!-- video post -->
                        <ul style="width:170px;"><!-- hidden links level 2 -->
                            <li ><a href="mix-to-picture.html">Mix to Picture</a></li>
                            <li><a href="adr-film-tv.html">ADR for Film & TV</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- End hidden links level 2 -->
                    </li><!-- END video post -->
                    <li><a href="isdn-services.html">ISDN Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pharma.html">Pharmaceutical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="audio-books.html">Audio Books</a></li>               
                  </ul><!-- End hidden links level 1 -->
            </li><!-- END what we do -->
          </ul>             
        </nav><!-- /Navigation  -->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
nav ul ul li a {
padding: 5px 10px;
color: #c8c8c8;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff; 
    background: #2b191c;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a bit of an issue with style precedence.

You've got this style selector set, I assume to cover all of the other links:

`nav ul li:hover a`

Since your second unordered list is within an `<li>` of the first unordered lists, it's elements inherit this style as well.

After that, you've also got:

`li:hover a`

Which is even more broad, and again overlaps with your desired style.

These two declarations are taking precedence because of the fact that they are in a separate stylesheet which is loaded after the stylesheet with your more specific style.

You have two choices here, the best being to re-optimize all of your styles so that there is less overlap, and less chance of styles fighting each other. This would mean creating fewer, and more specific styles that do a more effective job of covering your site. Things like `nav ul li:hover > a` using the `>` selector could be useful.

Alternatively, you can try moving the styles around so that the proper precedence by order is given. (I haven't checked to make sure if order is the only contributing factor, so you may have to do some re-optimizing anyways, if simply moving the style does not work)

Comment: As an added tip, you may want to analyze your reasons for having so many separate stylesheets.. It can be useful to create different files for organization purposes sometimes, but it does often lead to problems with style precedence, and it can make it harder to track down issues. If you find you don't really need separate files, it might be worth using a single stylesheet.

Comment: Blake Mann, I tried what you suggested and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your project works fine in this JSFiddle I made using the exact code you have. I think your problem is you probably didn't link the css file to your HTML. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ym2cL/

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp